# Push Notifcations working but connectToFcm() is not defined

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My push notifications are working (albeit a bit buggy: PNs while in foreground cause the app to crash) - I'm receiving a notification on my device, but in AppDelegate > tokenRefreshNotification() "connectToFcm()" is unresolved and had to comment it out. Where is that method defined? I'm apparently missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`connectToFcm` is a utility method defined in the [quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExample/AppDelegate.m#L194) & [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive#connect_to_messaging) as an example of what you might do.

```
- (void)connectToFcm {
 [[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error != nil) {
      NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
    } else {
      NSLog(@"Connected to FCM.");
    }
  }];
}
```

Its just broken out into a separate function as its called when the app becomes active as well as on token refresh. The swift equivalent is [in the Swift sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift#L113).

Comment: The link you have provided is no longer active. Just in case anyone is still looking for the answer.